# I wrote a code in two ways with just one line different but I am getting different results

Tags: python

I wrote a code in two ways with just one line different but I am getting different results. In one code I used else statement while in one I did not can someone please explain to me the difference between the two. I am a beginner at coding.

THE FIRST CODE

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        numMap = {}
        n = len(nums)

        # Build the hash table
        for i in range(n):
            numMap[nums[i]] = i

        # Find the complement
        for i in range(n):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            if complement in numMap and numMap[complement] != i:
                return [i, numMap[complement]]

        return []  # No solution found
```

THE SECOND ONE

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        numMap = {}
        n = len(nums)
        
    for i in range(n):
        numMap[nums[i]] = i

    for i in range (n):
        complement = target - nums[i] 
        if complement in numMap and numMap[complement] != i:
            return[i,numMap[complement]]
        else:
             return []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code does return from inside the `for` loop.
Thus it only executes the very first iteration of your loop and then returns from either the `if` or the `else` branch. **It will never reach the second iteration of the loop.**

In contrast, you first first code either returns from inside the loop (once the condition of the `if` statement is met) or it returns after iterating through the whole loop (if the condition of the `if` statement is never met while running through the loop).

Comment: Welcome :)
Feel free to mark an answer as accepted to show that your question was suficiently answered.

Answer (score 1):

In the first implementation the case of no solution (`return []`) will only be hit after the completion of the iteration (the second for loop).

In the second implementation, instead, the function will always return after checking the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already given correct answers. So just adding some code example.

As pointed out, your second code will always terminate in the first iteration. This is because you have used `return` statement under the `else` condition.

If you want to use the `if..else` structure, then do this:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        numMap = {}
        n = len(nums)
    
        for i in range(n):
            numMap[nums[i]] = i

        for i in range (n):
            complement = target - nums[i] 
            if complement in numMap and numMap[complement] != i:
                return[i,numMap[complement]]
            else:
                pass
        return []
```

The above code and your first code should give the same result.